# How can React js state props works after component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

How can i use my state and using on my component child by props?
coz i want to use in my child component the data like unit.

in parent i set like this:

```
const { unit } = this.state
```

and then i call child component with props

```
...
export default EditData extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      dataId: this.props.match.params.id,
      ...,
      measurement: ''
    }

    this.onTextboxChangeMeasurement = this.onTextboxChangeMeasurement.bind(this)
  }

  onTextboxChangeMeasurement(event){
    this.setState({
      measurement: event.target.value
    })
  }

  getData(){
    this.DataTicker.data(this.state.dataId)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          ...,
          measurement: res.measurement
        })
      })
  }

  render(){
    const {
      dataId,
      measurement
    } = this.state
    return(
      <DataTickerItem dataId={dataTickerId} unit={measurement}/>
    )
  }  
}
```

when i do `console.log(measurement)`, i see 2 result
the 1st is blank and the 2nd with value.

and i want to use the value on my child, but i cant coz the unit always set to 1st result.

Comment: if possible add more code from your component, questions is not clear

Comment: You don't give enough context. What is this `unit` value, is it static or fetched asynchronously, where are you using `console.log`, etc.

Comment: Spend 10 minutes on this website, you would have 80% less questions: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

When you set `unit={measurement}` in your child, it means - set childs' `unit` variable value to `measurement` (coming form parent). But you dont mention about any value for `measurement` in your parent. If you `const { unit } = this.state` in your parent, this would make more sense:

`<DataTickerItem dataId={dataTickerId} unit={unit}/>`

Now your DataTickerItem should have a `unit` variable with assigned `unit` from its parent.

Comment: yes, i already tried that one.
when i console.log unit it will show 2 result.

Comment: the 1st result is empty and

and the 2nd result with measurement value.

Comment: but when i use `<DataTickerItem dataId={dataTickerId} unit={unit}/>` , the unit only set to the 1st result

Comment: Still not clear to me. You say you set `const { unit } = this.state` in parent. **EditData** is your parent? There is no such statement